# Login Validation in android.

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am developing an android application. I want to validate Mobile no and password so that user can login. I've wrote some code for this. The problem is, if I enter wrong Mobile no and Password, it is validating as correct. Please let me know what is wrong I am doing in the code. I am new in android. This is the code below:

**insert2.php**

```
<?php

    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='welcome';
    $db='CoovaChilli';

    $con=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("database selection failed");

    $mobile=$_POST['Mobile'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    $select="select * from Insert1 where Mobile = '$mobile' AND Password = '$password'";

    if($r=mysql_query($select,$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

    EditText et1,et2;
    Button login;
    String Mobile=null;
    String Password=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    HttpPost httpPost;
    HttpClient client;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    int code;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v==login)
        {
            Mobile=et1.getText().toString();
            Password=et2.getText().toString();

            if(Mobile.isEmpty() || Mobile.length()<0 || Password.isEmpty() || Password.length()<0)
            {
                Toast t1=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all the fields", 2000);
                t1.show();
            }
            else
            {
                Varify();
            }
        }

    }   

    private void Varify()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert2.php");
        try
        {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair>pairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Mobile", Mobile));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",Password));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            is=entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Connection Success","Mission Success-1");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Log.e("Failed","Connection Failed");
        }
        try
        {
            BufferedReader r1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=r1.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb1.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb1.toString();
            Log.e("Result","Result1");
            Log.e("Mission Success-2","Success-2");
        }
        catch(Exception ex1)
        {
            Log.e("Fail","Fail...");
        }

        try
        {
            JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject(result);
            code=(obj1.getInt("code"));
            if(code==1)
            {
                Log.e("Match Found","MATCH FOUND");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("Match not found","Match Not Found");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e2)
        {
            Log.e("asdfghj","asdfghytre");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should brush up your php knowledge before you continue.

Comment: ***Stop, look, and listen.*** You are adding raw query parameters to your SQL query string. If an attacker tries to submit a password of `x'; DROP TABLE Insert1; -- ` then you'll be short a table.

Comment: please let me know why its not validating..plzz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pwd='welcome';
$db='CoovaChilli';

$con=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("database selection failed");

$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mobile']); # Secure the input!
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);

$flag['code']=0;

$select="select * from Insert1 where Mobile = '$mobile' AND Password = '$password'";
$r=mysql_query($select,$con); # This will always return something "true"

if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) { # You want to count rows instead.
    $flag['code']=1;
}
print(json_encode($flag));
```

Please remember that the MySQL extension is obsolet, and one should use the new MySQLi extension or PDO. You should take a look at those.

Comment: My bad, didn't see escaper (too much Java recently). Vote has been taken back.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$r=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($select,$con));
if($r>0)
    $flag['code']=1;
```

And it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='welcome';
    $db='CoovaChilli';

    $con=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("database selection failed");

    $mobile=$_POST['Mobile'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    $select="select * from Insert1 where Mobile = '$mobile' AND Password = '$password'";

    $r=mysql_query($select,$con);

    if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) 
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
    } else {
        $flag['code']=0;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```